# C: How to get string input with space in a structure in following code?

Tags: c

I just ended up writing these codes. It is a structure of data which is supposed to be written in the `FILE`. I want all the strings to be entered by the user with spaces in between. 
I used `fgets()`, but `fgets()` produces a newline in the time of reading the file. Any way to do it? And please explain if any buffer overflow occurs. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    FILE *student_records;

struct studentdetails{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    int class_room;
    char section[10];
    char fathername[20];
    char mothername[20];
}totalstudentdetails;

struct studentmarks{
    int physics;
    int chemistry;
    int maths;
    int biology;
    int english;
}totalstudentmarks;

int main()
{    
    student_records=fopen("studentrec.dat","a+");  


    printf("\n                  ADD STUDENT RECORDS          \n\n\n");
    printf("          Enter Student Name > ");
    scanf("%s",totalstudentdetails.name);
    printf("           Enter Student Age > ");
    scanf("%d", &totalstudentdetails.age);
    getchar();
    printf("         Enter Student Class > ");
    scanf("%d", &totalstudentdetails.class_room);
    getchar();
    printf("       Enter Student Section > ");
    scanf("%s", totalstudentdetails.section);
    printf("Enter Student Father's Name > ");
    scanf("%s",totalstudentdetails.fathername);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter Student mother's Name > ");
    scanf("%s",totalstudentdetails.mothername);
    getchar();
    fwrite(&totalstudentdetails, sizeof(totalstudentdetails), 1, student_records);

            /* Student marks details */

    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    printf("                 Marks Obtained(Out Of 100)         \n\n");
    printf("      Enter Mark In Physics > ");
    scanf("%d", &totalstudentmarks.physics);
    getchar();
    printf("    Enter Mark In Chemistry > ");
    scanf("%d", &totalstudentmarks.chemistry);
    getchar();
    printf("        Enter Mark In Maths > ");
    scanf("%d", &totalstudentmarks.maths);
    getchar();
    printf("      Enter Mark In Biology > ");
    scanf("%d", &totalstudentmarks.biology);
    getchar();
    printf("      Enter Mark In English > ");
    scanf("%d", &totalstudentmarks.english);
    getchar();
    fwrite(&totalstudentmarks, sizeof(totalstudentmarks), 1, student_records);


/* closing file */
fclose(student_records);
}
```

Comment: "I used fgets(), but fgets() produces a newline in the time of reading the file." --> Then lop off the optional `'\n'` is desired.   Avoid `scanf()`.

Comment: Can you explain a little please?

Comment: Please post some sample input and expected output.  That adds clarity to the question.